# Span of $(a x + b y )^n $ is exactly the space of $n$-dimensional homogeneous polynomials in $x$ and $y$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Actually, I need to prove that the Delta operator

$$ \Delta = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2 } + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2 } + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2 } $$

maps the space $P_k$ ($k$-dimensional homogeneous polynomials in $x,y,z$) surjectively to $P_{k-2}$.

We have

$$ \Delta [ (ax + b y + c z )^k] = k(k-1)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 )(ax + b y + c z )^{k-2} . $$

Now the proof would be done if $(ax + b y + c z )^{k-2}$ spans $P_{k-2}$.

It seems very reasonable. But I cannot figure out a proof. Could anyone help me?

Comment: You can try to vary coefficeints $a,b,c$ to obtain monomials $x^py^qz^r$, $p+q+r=n$ as a linear combination of $(ax+by+cz)^n$.

Comment: And yes, it's sufficient to solve the case which you've mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will show that $$\{(x+ky)^n : 1 \le k \le n+1\}$$
spans the $n$-dimensional homogeneous polynomials in $x$ and $y$. Note that polynomials $$v_j := {n \choose j}x^{n-j}y^j, \quad 0 \le j \le n$$
form a basis for our space. We have
$$(x+ky)^n = \sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j} k^j x^{n-j}y^j = \sum_{j=0}^n k^jv_j, \quad 1 \le k \le n+1$$

so these polynomials written as rows in the basis $\{v_j\}_{0\le j \le n}$ have coordinates
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1^2 & 1^3 & \cdots & 1^{n}\\
1 & 2^2 & 2^3 & \cdots & 2^{n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & (n+1)^2 & (n+1)^3 & \cdots & (n+1)^n
\end{bmatrix}$$
This is a Vandermonde matrix and hence invertible so we conclude that $\{(x+ky)^n : 1 \le k \le n+1\}$ is linearly independent. Since there are precisely $n+1$ vectors, which is the dimension of our space, we conclude that it is a basis. In particular, it spans the space.

Comment: smart  proof！But how to generalize it to the $x,y,z$ case?

Comment: @S.Kohn We need to write $x^py^qz^r$ with $p+q+r = n$ as a linear combination of $(ax+by+cz)^n$. Using the claim for $(p+q)$-dimensional homogeneous polynomials in $x$ and $y$ we have $$x^py^qz^r = \sum_k \alpha_k(a_k x + b_k y)^{p+q}z^r.$$
Now, each $(a_k x + b_k y)^{p+q}z^r$ is an $n$-dimensional homogeneous polynomial in variables $a_k x + b_k y$ and $z$ so using the claim we have $$(a_k x + b_k y)^{p+q}z^r = \sum_j \beta_j(c_j(a_k x+b_k y) + d_j z)^n = \sum_j \beta_j(a_{k,j}' x+b_{k,j}' y + c_{k,j}' z)^n$$
so plugging that back in the relation for $x^py^qz^r$ yields the claim.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this really smart proof. Actually, this problem comes from the book by B. Hall, 'quantum theory for mathematicians'. see page 275. He gives some hint for a different proof. But I cannot figure it out.